# C# logging and debugging communications between my program and sql database on the internet?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, logging, trace

I'm writing an application that connects to an sql database over the internet , is there anyway to trace ,log and debug the communication (login ,queries ...etc.) between my application and the SQL server : I'm using the SqlConnection Class , and SqlDataAdapter Class  ?

*note the code is already quiet large so I can't log everything manually through code .

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Profiler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(v=sql.80).aspx) is great tool to help trace what goes on between your code and SQL server.